# Simplicial complices on unlabelled vertices

Tags: combinatorics

My question is about (abstract) simplicial complices.
In particular, how many are they if I consider $n$ unlabelled vertices?

For example, if $n=4$, the two complices
$$
\{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}\}
$$
and
$$
\{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 4\}\}
$$
are the same, but not
$$
\{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}\}
$$
(since the last two sides of this one intersect in one vertex).

If $n=3$, there are 5 of them (while the Dedekind number for 3 is 20).
They are:
- dim=2
$$\{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$$
- dim=1
$$\{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}\}$$
$$\{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}\}$$
$$\{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2\}\}$$
- dim 0
$$\{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}\}$$

Since this last observation I think that the answer is not the Dedekind number, but please prove me wrong if you think it is.

Thank you in advance,
Davide

PS: I don't know exactly what tags should I give to this question apart from "combinatorics".

Update: Since I had no feedback from the community, I asked the same question also on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/178529/42995).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/178536/42995) from MathOverflow, given by [Brendan McKay](https://mathoverflow.net/users/9025/brendan-mckay):

> This is http://oeis.org/A006602 .  I checked the numbers there.
>
> The correspondence is because the maximal elements form an antichain
>   cover.